# How to bookmark code snippets in intellij ide?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

I have line of code which may be not optimized enough, so i want to keep track of them and later try to improve them. Is there any way to tag code and later find them easily by their tag name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just use

```
//todo optimize code
your code
```

or

```
//fixme fix bug
your code
```

and later you can find them in the TODO tool section at the bottom of the IDE. here todo and fixme tags are keywords. You can add more customized tag in File->settings->TODO.